# Parse a date from json

Tags: java, android, json

I want get Date from following Json file 
which has string:

```
{"Notice":[{"nid":1,"title":"Greeting","notice":"hello","priority":"","date":"Jan 30, 2015 11:35:29 AM","userid":"1"}]}
```

- I want to parse it using following code:

  ```
  java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(object.getString("date"));
  d.setDate(temp);
  ```
- but it gives me Exception:

  ```
  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jan 30, 2015 11:35:29 AM" (at offset 0)
  ```

if any suggestion always welcome.

Comment: Well... I think its clear that your date-format is very much different form the format of date string. Change your date-format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the date format to : `MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a` to parse the date.

```
java.util.Date temp = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a").parse(object.getString("date"));
```

Comment: Please don't give direct answers to "I won't read the documentation or anything, just correct my code" kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `Locale` when you create the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d',' yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.UK).parse(object.getString("date"));
```

And use the correct format.

Comment: @user3651256 Sorry have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String dtStart = "Jan 30, 2015 11:35:29 AM";  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz ",Locale.getDefault);  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```